# How do I time out a ASP.NET MVC logged in user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I time out the session a ASP.NET MVC logged in user after about 5 mins or so forcing him to have to login in order to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MVC is just like WebForms in that they both run on ASP.NET and assuming you're using Forms Authentication you can either:

- Force the user to logout with `FormsAuthenitcation.SignOut()` which will clear their authentication cookie; or
- Set the forms authentication timeout value (default is 30 minutes). For example:

> ```
> <system.web>
>   <authentication mode="Forms">
>     <forms timeout="5"/>
>   </authentication>
> </system.web>
> ```

Comment: Forms authentication and session are two separate things, although I think for what the question is asking, this will suffice.